# Intellisense does not work for Javascript in VS 2019 PREVIEW

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I honestly dont know what I did or happened, but intellisense is switch off and Javascripts appears as just plain text and unless I format it, the basic formatting and curly braces are gone by default

Everything else is ok

Please advise how I can get it back

thanks

Ehi